# Calling a function or method by reflection in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, reflection

I am just going through a problem that I haven't before in C/C++, and I have no idea how to solve it. Reflection. I need to call a function or method by a *string* that was given by the user. Not just this, I also need to give the function or method some parameters and get its result if any.

Imagine the user has typed `printSomething`.

I need to evaluate `"printSomething"(paramA, paramB)`. Of course, the function or method `T printSomething()` is defined.

How is the best way I can do it?

Comment: `dlsym` could help you.  Or `std::map<std::string, std::function<resulttype(paramtype1, paramtype2)> >`

Comment: In general, there is no built-in feature to do reflective function calls.

Comment: What if the function has more parameters? I mean, the number of parameters may vary, depending on the function called...

Comment: Do it from within `gdb`.

Comment: @RodrigoSiqueira C++ is compiled, so the set of functions that are ultimately called is determined once program translation is complete. You have to decide on the set of functions that can be called. Aside from that, the sky is the limit, but as in my answer, you have to define a parser and interpreter to dispatch to those functions. It's not actually reflection, but defining your own language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a structure mapping from strings to pointers to functions or methods (member functions).

C++ doesn't provide such a structure; you will have to build it yourself, passing in the name-strings and the pointers. Conversion of parameters and return values to and from strings also needs to be implemented. The language has no conventions or ideas about how this is to be done, so you must specify it.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen this idea on my researching. I was looking for a different idea.

Comment: @RodrigoSiqueira The only middle ground is to try to modify a compiler, such as using Clang's library interfaces, to avoid starting from scratch. That's not really reflection; it's just leveraging a library, even if you add some reflection to the language (which sounds pretty challenging). You're probably better off constraining yourself to the subset you want, because C++ is Really Complicated.

Comment: @RodrigoSiqueira Note that "build it yourself" can be simplified by using macros and preprocessing to add function declarations that add themselves to said data structure, adding limited reflection within the language.

Comment: Yeah, I know it. I was trying to find a different way of doing it other than mapping. Of course that, if I can't figure it out, I'll do it this way.

Comment: +1: I once created a Matlab interface to a sizeable C++ library using mostly this technique.

Comment: @aschepler This is almost the kind of thing I want to do.

Comment: @RodrigoSiqueira If you haven't, take a look at Swig.